# How to configure SSL to call other REST services through dynamic url in Apcahe Camel Method tod

Tags: java, ssl, apache-camel, quarkus

Good morning, I am currently working with apache camel and Quarkus and I am presented for the first time with a scenario that had not happened to me before, now I am working with dynamic url of the following type to call:

```
https://localhost:8080/users/{user}/customers
```

These services are in SSL, so the call to SSL must be configured, for non-dynamic url I used the following line:

```
.to(configureSsl.setupSSLContext(getCamelContext(), "https://localhost:8081/api/FindPrepaidAccountByDocument"))
```

Where my ConfigureSSL class is as follows:

```
package org.tmve.customer.ms.route;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.Endpoint;
import org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpComponent;
import org.apache.camel.support.jsse.KeyManagersParameters;
import org.apache.camel.support.jsse.KeyStoreParameters;
import org.apache.camel.support.jsse.SSLContextParameters;
import org.apache.camel.support.jsse.TrustManagersParameters;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.ConfigProvider;

@Slf4j
public class ConfigureSsl {
    
    private String password = ConfigProvider.getConfig().getValue("client.password", String.class);
    private String resource = ConfigProvider.getConfig().getValue("client.file", String.class);
    
     public Endpoint setupSSLContext(CamelContext camelContext, String url) throws Exception {

            KeyStoreParameters keyStoreParameters = new KeyStoreParameters();
            /*log.info(resource);*/
            /*log.info(password);*/
            keyStoreParameters.setResource(resource);
            keyStoreParameters.setPassword(password);

            KeyManagersParameters keyManagersParameters = new KeyManagersParameters();
            keyManagersParameters.setKeyStore(keyStoreParameters);
            keyManagersParameters.setKeyPassword(password);
            /*log.info("keyManagersParameters "+ keyManagersParameters);*/

            TrustManagersParameters trustManagersParameters = new TrustManagersParameters();
            trustManagersParameters.setKeyStore(keyStoreParameters);
            /*log.info("trustManagersParameters "+ trustManagersParameters);*/

            SSLContextParameters sslContextParameters = new SSLContextParameters();
            sslContextParameters.setKeyManagers(keyManagersParameters);
            sslContextParameters.setTrustManagers(trustManagersParameters);
            /*log.info("sslContextParameters "+ sslContextParameters);*/

            HttpComponent httpComponent = camelContext.getComponent("https", HttpComponent.class);
            httpComponent.setSslContextParameters(sslContextParameters);
            httpComponent.setX509HostnameVerifier(new AllowAllHostnameVerifier());
            /*log.info("httpComponent "+ httpComponent); */

            return httpComponent.createEndpoint(url);
        }

}
```

But now for the dynamic url I need to use the toD method of apache camel for dynamic url, however, I don't know how to configure the SSL part in dynamic url in the toD method, what I used for the non-dynamic url to method does not work for me in the toD method

I tried like this but it gives me an error on the line:

```
.toD(configureSsl.setupSSLContext(getCamelContext(),"https://localhost:8080/users/${exchangeProperty[user_id]}/customers?bridgeEndpoint=true"))
```

What can I do in this case to add my SSL configuration to my dynamic url in apache camel using the toD method, otherwise I get the following error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but if I recall that problem occurs when reaching to localhost with SSL.
In this example, I registred the X509HostnameVerifier as NoopHostnameVerifier instance, and I refer to this one in my Route. I guess there are other ways of configuring this.

https://github.com/apache/camel-quarkus/blob/main/integration-tests/platform-http-proxy-ssl/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/quarkus/component/platform/http/proxy/ssl/it/Routes.java

I hope this helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).